# Guard is skipped when it should not be

Tags: haskell, semantics

I have the following snippet of code

```
module Main where

main :: IO()
main = do
   ne <- getLine
   c <- getLine
   putStrLn $ show $ foo c (words ne)

foo :: String -> [String] -> Integer
foo c (n:e:_) =
   foo' (read c::Integer) (read e::Integer) (read n::Integer) [2..]
   where foo' c e n (x:xs)
      | mod (x^e) n == c = mod x n
      | otherwise = foo' c e n xs
```

Which works as expected except when given the following input:

```
9 3 
2
```

The first guard is skipped and an infinite loop is entered.
The way I see this is that
`foo'` should first be called with `2 9 3` which would result in `mod (2^9) 3 == 2` which is true and should result in the value `mod 2 9` but this is not the case.

I am sure I am missing something trivial here, but I just cant see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *e* and *n* the wrong way round in the definition of *foo'* (*n* comes before *e* in *foo*, but it's the other way around in *foo'*).  So you are not passing 2 9 3, you're passing 2 3 9.

Comment: Always something trivial... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`foo "2" ["9","3"]` will result in `foo' 2 3 9 [2..]`, not `foo' 2 9 3 [2..]`.  Got your arguments mixed up?